# How do I align the respective box right-bottom of the container using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZarQ.jpg)

I'm trying to align the green border box in the right corner, but unsuccessfully, doesn't anyone have an idea?

```css
.gallery {
    display: flex;
    height: 480px;
    width: 1170px;
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    outline: 3px solid black;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
}

.gallery .column:last-child {
    width: 770px;
    height: 224px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    border: 3px solid green;
}

.gallery .column:last-child .box {
    height: 224px;
    width: 770px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="suggested-text">
                <h2>Quae ab illo inventore</h2>
                <p>Architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt</p>
                <button type="button">Shop now</button>
            </div>
            <img src="img/Bitmaplaptops.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting `justify-content: flex-end` and `align-items: flex-end` on the `.gallery` and `.gallery .column:last-child` selectors, the green border box will be aligned to the bottom-right corner of the container.

**Example:**

```css
.gallery {
    display: flex;
    height: 480px;
    width: 1170px;
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    outline: 3px solid black;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    /* Align items horizontally to the right */
    align-items: flex-end;
    /* Align items vertically to the bottom */
}

.gallery .column:last-child {
    width: 770px;
    height: 224px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    /* Align items horizontally to the right */
    align-items: flex-end;
    /* Align items vertically to the bottom */
    border: 3px solid green;
}

.gallery .column:last-child .box {
    height: 224px;
    width: 770px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="suggested-text">
                <h2>Quae ab illo inventore</h2>
                <p>Architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt</p>
                <button type="button">Shop now</button>
            </div>
            <img src="img/Bitmaplaptops.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```